# More Logon Options link no longer available to allow Yahoo sign on

Tags: support, login

I used to sign on to Stack Overflow with my Yahoo email credentials which I would access via a "More Login Options" link that was available on the Stack Overflow sign on screen.

Is my account forever inaccessible or is this just a blip?